# How can I control an electric train?

Tags: raspberry-pi, voltage-divider, h-bridge

I want to control electronic train, using an H-bridge and a voltage divider to detect if there is a train or not.  (Whether the motor is connected to the wires or not.)

When the yellow wire is "+" and when the green wire is "-", this crcuit works fine, and I can detect the train.

But I want the train to be able to return.  When the green wire is the "+" this circuit doesn't work at all.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: My circuit]

Comment: Include a proper **schematic** of your setup, what you show is a "hookup" which shows what connects to what. It doesn't tell us much about how the system **works**.

Comment: Put a current sense resistor in the source lead of the lower FET of each side.  Or maybe use an INA219 high side current shunt monitor which you can read over I2C from the pi, given that lacks an ADC.  The low side shunt and a comparator and threshold adjust pot could get you a digital "presence" signal though.

Comment: What value is that current sense resistor? (this is why we use proper labelled circuit diagrams)

Comment: Whatever you do, don't directly connect something monitoring the H-bridge/motor circuit to your pi in the manner pictured, as that's a great way to kill it.  You'll need clamping circuitry, and you want to connect it above or below the bridge, not to the bridge outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions !